# Styling the stroke of an SVG in CSS's pseudo attribute 'content: url()'

Tags: css, svg

I have a SVG which I imported via

```
.nav-arrow::after {
    content: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,xevr...);
}
```

Now I want to define the color of the stroke via CSS, which doesn't work.
Do you have an idea how to import the SVG without any HTML and still being able to style it?

that's my SVG:

```
<svg class="nav-arrow" height="40" width="40">
    <g fill="#fff">
        <path stroke="#a01b1b" stroke-width="2" d="M 0 5 L 20 20 L 0 35" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: edit the base64 content to set the stroke to whatever it needs to be.

Comment: I can't do that, because I want it to be customizable via a SCSS variable.

Comment: share the SVG you are using in a runnable example

Comment: Well it's not like there's another alternative other than give up altogether. You chould have multiple cursors with different strokes and switch between them I suppose.

Comment: Are you using webpack with your scss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case you can use the SVG as mask and adjust the background color:

```css
.box {
   display:inline-block;
   width:40px;
   height:60px;
   position:relative;
}

.box::before,
.box::after{
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
}
/* The stroke */
.box::after {
   background:var(--c,red);
   -webkit-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="5 0 10 40" height="40" width="40"><path fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M 0 5 L 20 20 L 0 35" /></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
           mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="5 0 10 40" height="40" width="40"><path fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M 0 5 L 20 20 L 0 35" /></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
}
/* The fill */
.box::before {
    background:#f1f1f1;
   -webkit-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="5 0 10 40" height="40" width="40"><path d="M 0 5 L 20 20 L 0 35" /></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
           mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="5 0 10 40" height="40" width="40"><path d="M 0 5 L 20 20 L 0 35" /></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--c:blue;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--c:green;"></div>
```

Comment: I upvoted it because it's a good answer, but there's still one problem: I still need the white background-color. In your example the `fill` is `transparent`. If I change it to any other color there's just a 40 x 40px box.

Comment: @Dop4miN you can consider another mask, check the update